# IBM Bluemix raspberry pi send sensor data

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, ibm-cloud, iot

I have a Raspberry pi 2 where I am reading sensor data and displaying it on the screen; here is the code I am running on Raspberry pi:

```
#include "eHealth.h"

void loop() {
    float temperature = eHealth.getTemperature();
    printf("Temperature : %f \n", temperature);
    delay(2000);
}

int main(){
while(1){
    loop();
    }
return 0;
}
```

The code runs very well and the temperature is displayed on the command line. I want to make it an IoT application but I am a beginner and I am not sure how to set up. I tried IBM Bluemix and registered the device. It says the device is active but set your device to send data to visualize. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This [tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/raspberry-pi-4/) walks you through how to connect your raspberry pi to the IoT platform.

Comment: The tutorial doesn't seem to mention how to make the RaspberryPi send data to anywhere though - which, I think, is what the OP is asking?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to connect your Pi and the platform using Node-Red on your Pi and creating a Watson IoT Platform Node. Here is video on how to do so:
http://www.ibm.com/internet-of-things/ecosystem/devices/raspberry-pi/